# Is IBM Cloud Case Management the same as IBM Case Manager?

Tags: ibm-cloud

just wondering if this documentation relates to IBM Case Manager on Cloud or its a completely separate product entirely.

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/case-management

Comment: Are you looking for additional help with IBM Case Manager? I am happy to help if this response doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know. For now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is for dealing with support cases for IBM Cloud.